# regexp_matches better way to get rid of returning curly brackets

Tags: postgresql

Is there some better way to trim `{""}` in result of regexp_matches than:

```
trim(trailing '"}' from trim(leading '{"' from regexp_matches(note, '[0-9a-z \r\n]+', 'i')::text))
```

Comment: `regexp_matches` returns an array of all matches. The string representation of an array contains the curly braces. The question is what do you want to do with each array element? How do you use the result of the `regexp_match()` function?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`regexp_matches()` returns an array of all matches. The string representation of an array contains the curly braces that's why you get them.

If you just want a list of all matched items, you can use `array_to_string()` to convert the result into a "simple" text data type:

```
array_to_string(regexp_matches(note, '[0-9a-z \r\n]+', 'i'), ';')
```

If you are only interested in the first match, you can select the first element of the array:

```
(regexp_matches(note, '[0-9a-z \r\n]+', 'i'))[1]
```

Comment: I wanted to get rid of rubbish characters in the text field, so `array_to_string` is what i needed. Thanks for clarification!