# Convert text[] generated by regexp_maches back to character varying

Tags: sql, postgresql

Originally, there were some invalid character varying in the column postal_code. [The valid form is `[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]\s[0-9][A-Z][0-9]`]. After I executing the following sql command

```
CREATE table public.valid_geo 
AS 
SELECT regexp_matches(postal_code, '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]\s[0-9][A-Z][0-9]') AS postal_code, 
       SUM(total) AS X, 
       (SUM(total)/COUNT(tran_num)) AS Y,  
       COUNT(tran_num) AS Z 
FROM public.raw_data AS postal_code 
GROUP BY postal_code
```

I got a table with all the value like {"J4D 4K9"} for column [post_code]. Is there a way to convert the value in this column back to 6-digit character varying (Like: J4D4K9[With out the space and '{' '}' ])?
Note:
I have tried to just access the first element in each array. Then I got the text 'J4D 4K9'. Is there a possible way to convert this text to the character varying without the space in it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287274/regexp-matches-better-way-to-get-rid-of-returning-curly-brackets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regexp\_matches better way to get rid of returning curly brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287274/regexp-matches-better-way-to-get-rid-of-returning-curly-brackets)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Just using the replace function to get rid of the space https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432086/remove-all-spaces-from-a-string-in-sql-server